# Open popup after scroll to area

Tags: jquery, html, popup, scrollto

I have popup that fades on page load:

```
$("#popup").fadeIn(500).on("load", function(e){
    $('body').addClass('modalIn');
});
```

Inside popup there's link that scrolls to div #section which contains another link that triggers another popup:

```
<a href="#section">learn more</a>
```

Code that opens my popup in div #section *(prepared for having there another popups).*

```
$(".steps a").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var selectedModal = $(this).data("modal");
    $(".modals").fadeIn();
    $(".modal").hide();
    $("#"+selectedModal).fadeIn();
    $('body').addClass('modalIn');
    $.scrollify.disable();
    $('body').on('scroll', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
})
$(".modals").on("click", function(){
    $(".modals, .modal").fadeOut();
    $('body').removeClass('modalIn');
    $.scrollify.enable();       
});
```

My div #section contains following link:

```
<a href="#modal-1" data-target="#myModal" data-modal="modal-1">Open modal 1</a>
```

I want to open another popup **#modal-1** automatically when user click link "Read more" in first popup (that shows on page load).

I've tried to make this with following code using scrollTo plugin, but unfortunately this doesn't work propely.

First popup fades on page load, I click link to #section and right after that script shows alert window (made for tests) After closing alert window page scrolls to #section.

How to make it work to show alert/trigger popup only after window scrolls to div #section (reaches it)?

```
$('a[href="#section"]').click(function() {
$(window).scrollTo('#section', {
    onAfter: function() {
        alert('test');
    }
})
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to put the alert in a setTimeout.  Alerts will fire before page event have a chance to complete.  Even if you put it in a setTimeout with 0 delay, the setTimeout drops the alert to the bottom of the stack, allowing the rest of your code time to complete.  Try this:

```
$('a[href="#section"]').click(function() {
  $(window).scrollTo('#section', {
   onAfter: function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
       alert('test');
     }, 100)

  })
});
```

Comment: You can change 100 to any amount of time you would like in milliseconds.  You might need to play with it to figure out the best amount of time to delay the modal opening.